# Nginx Regex - Matching Slug

Tags: regex, nginx, slug

I have a slug like this

```
/my-product-group-any-name/my-product-name-just-name/1500
```

I'm trying to make nginx location matching with my regex to match that slug, currently my regex is like this

```
^\/([a-z0-9]+((-)+[a-z0-9]+)*)*
```

when I'm trying to add backslash it throw error (I tested on [Rubular.Com](http://rubular.com/r/UkNLFoXyD7)). I'm still consfused on how to match that slug. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should solve your problem.

```
^(\/([a-z0-9]+((-)+[a-z0-9]+)*))*
```

You've missed additional round brackets for the slashs in combination with the alpha-numeric-string